# Data structure, why this struct size is 40 bytes not 29 bytes

Tags: c, data-structures

As title

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
//412447038 chang ting hao
int main(void){
struct stint {int f1, f2, f3;};         // 12 bytes
struct stfloat {float f4; double f5;};  // 12bytes

struct sam{
       char utype;                  // 1 bytes
       float f6, f7;                    // 8 bytes
       double f8;                   // 8 bytes

       union{struct stint f11;                  // 12bytes
             struct stfloat f12;}               // 12bytes
        f13; };                 // 12bytes    =  29 bytes
struct sam s[100];
printf("sam size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1]));                //   sam size: 40
printf("utype size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].utype));        //   utype size: 1
printf("f6 size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].f6));              //   f6 size: 4
printf("f7 size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].f7));              //   f7 size: 4
printf("f8 size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].f8));              //   f8 size: 8
printf("f1 size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].f13.f11.f1));      //   f1 size: 4
printf("f2 size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].f13.f11.f2));      //   f2 size: 4
printf("f3 size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].f13.f11.f3));      //   f3 size: 4
printf("f4 size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].f13.f12.f4));      //   f4 size: 4
printf("f5 size:  %i\n", sizeof(s[1].f13.f12.f5));      //   f8 size: 8
```

I caluate the structure sizes and using pointer to check out every element in the struct, I fond out utype is 4 byte and f4 is 8 bytes, why?

Comment: Are you asking "Why are my C structures padded? What is alignment?"

Comment: [**Structure padding and packing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing)

Comment: Should be using `%zu` to print `size_t` values like those generated by `sizeof`, btw.

Comment: Also [**Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)  I'll let others decide if this question is a duplicate of that.

Comment: You might find [`offsetof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) interesting.